# Show only features which are transboundary across two features of another layer

Tags: qgis

I have two layers in my QGIS project: 1x shapefile with country borders, and 1x geojson which plots segment features.

Is there a way to only select/show those segments which are transboundary, i.e. which are crossing AT LEAST one border of the features (countries) in the shapefile?

To explain in words: I need to select only those electricity grids which are connecting two or more countries, not domestic ones.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example with:

- Country polygon= `Countries` layer with `id`, `country` fields
- Electric cable line = `Lines` layer with `id`, `cable` fields

Before start, please download and install [`refFunctions`](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin.

(1) First step is extracting nodes of your cable lines.

`Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector geometry tools | Extract nodes`

[image]

(2) It will return `Nodes` layer (green points at each node of line). Each point (node) is expressed as a row in the attribute table.

[image]

(3) Open the attribute table of this `Nodes` layer, and create a new field (let's say `straddle`) by expression below:

```
CASE 
WHEN count_distinct(geomwithin('Countries', 'country'), group_by:= cable) >= 2
THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END
```

geomwithin() function is provided by `refFunctions` plugin.

[image]

This will distinguish lines which straddle multiple countries.

[image]

(4) Final task is to `Join` these tables.

Open `Layer Properties | Joins` and join Lines and Nodes using `cable` (cable name) as join-target field. Now you can filter your cable layer (straddle = 'Yes').

[image]

......there must be more sophisticated approaches.

Comment: Isn't a fomula like `geomwithin('countries','id') is null` a one step, direct answer to giacomo question ? Works perfectly to me ...

Comment: This is really great, I am very thankful for your help and the time you took to show a step-by-step procedure! Thanks a lot!